# Java: object fields assignment

Tags: java

I am trying to understand something that may be very simple, so I apologize if I am looking like a rookie.

I have this java class:

```
public class Student {
    public String name = "";
    public int age = 0;
    public String major = "Undeclared";
    public boolean fulltime = true;

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + " Major: " + major);
    }

    public boolean isFullTime() {
        return fulltime;
    }
}
```

And this class from which I call the first one:

```
public class TestStudent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student bob = new Student();
        Student jian = new Student();
        bob.name = "Bob";
        bob.age = 19;
        jian = bob;
        jian.name = "Jian";
        System.out.println("Bob s Name: " + bob.name);
    }
}
```

This will print:

> Bob s Name: Jian

I am curious about how the assignments are done there.

Comment: Cause `bob` and `jian` is referring to the same object.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, i upvoted all of them, because they were right. I chose @AnthonyGrist's answer because it was more clarifying. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `Student bob = new Student()` you're creating an instance of the Student class, and saving a reference to that location in memory in the `bob` variable.

When you do `jian = bob`, you're saving that same reference to the memory location in the `jian` variable, so now `jian` and `bob` point to *exactly the same instance of the Student class*.

Answer (score 3):

This line causes `jian` and `bob` to point to the **same** object:

```
jian = bob;
```

So changing `jian` name will also change `bob` name.

```
jian.name = "Jian";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Student bob = new Student();
Student jian = new Student();
// you've created two objects and two references 
bob.name = "Bob"; // bob's name is now Bob
bob.age = 19; // bob's age is now 19
jian = bob; // the jian reference is now referring to the same object as bob
jian.name = "Jian"; // jian and bob are now referring to an object whose name is changed to Jian
System.out.println("Bob s Name: " + bob.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Jian` has reference to `bob` object.

Answer (score 2):

you are copying the reference of bob to jian.

now both are pointing the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Assignement it's due to the line

```
jian = bob;
```

With this line, you replace the instance of Jian's Object by Bob's Object.
That's mean Jian instance become Bob instance, but Bob instance keep existing.

So when you change the name of Jian, internally you change the name of Bob

Answer (score 1):

As writed before, your variables bob and jian is link to the same object in memory. That was, for not primitives types when you use = operator you copy link. If you need create anoter object that will contains fields with previously entered data you need implement clone method. Or you can add constructor that get your object in parametrs and copy your field.
Example:

```
jian = bob.clone();
```

[About this on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29)

By constructor:

```
public Student(Strudent obj){
    this.name = obj.name;
    this.age = obj.age;
}
```

In main:
    Student jian = new Student(bob);

And you can find many variants of solving you problems. Use any variant that you like.